# Create a CentOS Guest img over Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, centos, virtual-machine, xen

I want to create a basic CentOS 5.8 system from scratch.

for now i build my own img for Ubuntu Guest (debootstrap), my host is a Ubuntu 12.04.1LTS but  I don't know how to make for a CentOS, **is possible build CentOS from Ubuntu?**

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it, but [it seems that](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/virt/2009-July/001123.html) febootstrap can install a CentOS.

Comment: Yes, but note that only old versions. The newer version is focused on creating something called "supermin appliances" and is not generally useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock) on Ubuntu to build RPM packages. One of the things mock does is create and maintain chroots (similar to pbuilder for Debian), so you could try creating a chroot with it and building from there.